# In Windows ServerR2 I need 3.5 netframework IIS manager but .netframework is installed?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, .net-framework-version

In IIS manager when we creating application pool there is only listing of 2.0 and 4.0

but 3.5 installed in the machine

but for my application i need 3.5 
thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

There will show 2.0 and 4.0. There will not show others.

Comment: If you show an official documentation link like this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-using-aspnet-35-and-aspnet-45 then a thousand words can be saved.

Comment: Friend I am a new to help. Hope soon will improve myself.